# angular ionic 7 typescript -> How to start ion-segment scrolled to end horizontally

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic7, ion-segment

The pre selected segment is being cutted off the screen when the component is inicialized, only after selecting another segment the focus is correct.

Already tried scrollIntoView on ngAfterViewInit, also Change Detector Ref but did not worked.

**Expected behavior:**
The segment must load horizontally scrolled to the end of the screen.
[image: Showld load like this]
**Current Behavior:**
[image: Now is loading like this]

link with a demo of the behavior [https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic6-angular13-tirtee?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic6-angular13-ge4xzz?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: Can you please provide some interactive demo to better understand the issue?

Comment: More details added